# how to prevent a cell in tableview to be moved

Tags: swift, uitableview

I need to prevent last cell from second section from being moved and even to show the "right handle" that appears when tableview is editing.

I create cellsObject based upon a model which has an "identity" property in a Table with two cells. when using

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {}
```

I move from one array to the other based upon the section.

how and where should I block to that cell with that identity from being moved anywhere? I tried this inside cellForRow:

```
if model.identity == "DoNotMove" l {
            cell.isEditing = false
            cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = false
            cell.editingAccessoryType = .none
        }
```

but is not working, tested the same inside the method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {}
```

with crash result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the data source method [tableView(_:canMoveRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614927-tableview)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
       canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
```

and return `false` for the index path

Comment: hi, that cell is appearing (always as the last one) only if there is at least another "normal" cell in the second section, otherwise I set a tableFooterView. that's why I think I should use the identity. do you know how to solve this

Comment: Get the model item at the given index path and `return model.identity != "DoNotMove"`